# Does a react-native native android module need to ask permissions?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm developing an app with React-Native that requires me to write a native Android module for React. Within this module, I'll use things such as the network, storage and camera. Do I need to put the permissions request within the module (runtime or manifest depending the SDK version) or does it need to be done within the React-Native Android app ?

Thanks in advance folks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both should work equally. But [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html) is the `react-native` documentation on `Android Permissions` for reference.